# ESM export * except from module

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

Given I have two imports with lots of named exports (too many to write them all out) and I want to reexport these except a few of them. In my case this is because a few exports collide.

As an example of what I want to archive lets assume we have two files:

`foo.js`:

```js
export const a = 1;
export const b = 2;
```

`bar.js`:

```js
export const b = 1;
export const c = 3;
```

If I want to aggregate and reexport them all using CommonJS I could do something like this:

```js
/* use rest destructuring to put everything except "b" into variable "foo" */
const { b, ...foo } = require("./foo"); 
const bar = require("./bar");

module.exports = {
    ...foo,
    ...bar
};
```

As I'm using typescript the closest I've gotten is using `export = { ... }` in a similar way:

```
import * as foo from "./foo";
import * as bar from "./bar";

const { b, ...foo2 } = foo;

export = {
    ...foo2,
    ...bar,
};
```

However it is my understanding this will create a file with CommonJS `module.exports` instead of a proper ESM module (and probably require `esModuleInterop`). And it is a typescript construct and not available when writing vanilla JS.

Is there a way to archive this using ESM `import` / `export` instead?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to archive this using ESM import / export instead?

No, not in pure standard ESM, not without doing what you're trying to avoid: Listing the named exports. There's no "rest" concept in ESM `import`/`export`.

I think you know this, but you could export an object with properties for `a`, `b`, and `c`, but that's a very different thing from re-exporting named exports. It wouldn't be a live binding, and the syntax for importing its parts is different from importing named exports (unless build-time tools like TypeScript or bundlers, etc. are involved).

Just FWIW, here's what that looks like (it's very similar to your TypeScript version near the end), but I don't think it's what you want:

`reexport.js`:

```
import * as foo from "./foo.js";
import * as bar from "./bar.js";

const { b, ...restOfFoo } = foo;
export default {
    ...restOfFoo,
    ...bar,
};
```

Then using it is:

```
// Import the object (which is the default export)
import stuff from "./reexport.js";

// Destructure into local vars (optional, but...)
const { a, b, c } = stuff;

// Use it...
console.log(a, b, c);
```

That's all standard ESM.

Comment: The major drawback is that it's longer possible to import the named exports, e.g. `import { a } from "./reexport"`

Comment: @ext - Right -- I said that in my second paragraph.